# Shell script to poll a directory and stop upon an event

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, scripting, while-loop

Need shell script to:
1/keep polling a directory "receive_dir" irrespective of having files or no files in it.
2/move the files over to another directory "send_dir".
3/the script should only stop polling upon a file "stopfile" get moved to "receive_dir". Thanks !!

My script:

```
until [ $i = stopfile ]
 do
   for i in `ls receive_dir`; do
     time=$(date +%m-%d-%Y-%H:%M:%S)
     echo $time
     mv receive_dir/$i send_dir/;
   done
done
```

This fails on empty directories and also is there any better way ?

Comment: polling sucks, read about libnotify =)

Comment: don't forget to put a sleep in your loop, or this will run as fast as it can, consuming a lot of CPU (maybe) on your box. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running on Linux, you might wish to consider [inotifywait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709860/shell-script-to-poll-a-directory-and-stop-upon-an-event)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ declare -f  tillStopfile
tillStopfile () 
 { 
     cd receive_dir
     [[ -d ../send_dir ]] || mkdir ../send_dir
     while true; do
         date +%m-%d-%Y-%H:%M:%S
         for f in *
         do
             mv "$f" ../send_dir
             [[ $f == "stopfile" ]] && break 2
         done
         sleep 3
     done
 }
$
```

Improvements

- while true ... break # 
    easier to control this loop
- cd receive_dir # 
    why not run in the "receive_dir"
- factor date out of inner loop  #
    unless you need to see each time-stamp?
- added suggested "sleep"
    # pick a suitable inteval

Run:

```
$ tillStopfile 2>/dev/null    # suppresses ls error messages
```

Comment: I might wait until all files in the current batch are moved rather than break immediately upon finding `stopfile`, but it depends on how the user expects files to be added to `receive_dir`.

Comment: This does not break upon "stopfile" in the receive_dir